# R Find sum of x or fewer rows

Tags: r

I have a function that ranks a variable based on # of occurrences.

```
rankTab <- function (x) 
{
    tab1 <- data.frame(table(x))
    tab1 <- tab1[order(-tab1$Freq), ]
    tab1
}
```

I'd like to run this across a data.frame with multiple columns and figure out a rough measure of cardinality by saying for each column, what % of values are covered by the 5 most frequently occurring values.  Something like this:

```
df$top_5_val_pct <- round(sapply(x, function(x) sum(rankTab(x)[1:max(5,nrow(x)),'Freq']) / length(x)), 4)
```

My problem is when there are < 5 values, I'm getting an NA as there aren't 5 rows to sum.  I've tried using min and max but can't figure out how to get 5 or fewer rows.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want % separately for each of the top 5: `lapply(iris, function(v) transform(rankTab(v)[1:5, ], pct = Freq/nrow(iris)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing the `sum()` to add in `na.rm = TRUE`

```
sum(rankTab(x)[1:5, "Freq"], na.rm = TRUE)
```

giving

```
df <- data.frame(A = sample(letters[1:4], 20, replace = TRUE), 
                 B = sample(letters[1:4], 20, replace = TRUE))

round(sapply(df, function(x) sum(sum(rankTab(x)[1:5, "Freq"], na.rm = TRUE)) / length(x)), 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a hard time parsing the code you're using to accomplish this, but going simply off of "what % of values are covered by the 5 most frequently occurring values" I'd do something like this:

```
sortTab <- function(x,n){
    t <- sort(table(x))
    sum(tail(t,n)) / sum(t)
}

sapply(mtcars,sortTab,n = 2)
```

where in this example, I'm finding the proportion covered by the two most common values.